# What is the value range from a dot-product between two normalized vectors?

Tags: vector

I've recently learned about the existence of dot product and I was wanted to know how to determine the value range between two normalized vectors.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Is this what you're looking for: http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vch09/vch09_6.html ?

Comment: Normalized vectors are between -1:1, and the dot product is `ax*bx+ay*by` It's fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 7):

The dot product of two normalized (unit) vectors will be a scalar value between -1 and 1.

Common useful interpretations of this value are

- when it is 0, the two vectors are perpendicular (that is, forming a 90 degree angle with each other)
- when it is 1, the vectors are parallel ("facing the same direction") and
- when it is -1, the vectors are anti-parallel ("facing opposite directions")

Because the dot product is, geometrically, the product of the magnitudes of the vectors and the cosine of the angle between them (\$\vert{a}\vert\vert{b}\vert \cos{\theta} \$) it also useful for finding \$\theta\$: it's just \$\arccos{(a \cdot b)}\$ since the magnitudes of the vectors are both one.

You may also be interested in interpretations of the dot product between *non*-normalized vectors, which is discussed in [this related question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/89831/how-do-i-interpret-the-dot-product-of-non-normalized-vectors).