# 2D Vector local to global space without trig/sqrt

Tags: 2d, vector, transformation, linear-algebra

Per [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182920/70301) to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/182919/70301), a cheap way (i.e., without trig/sqrt) to convert from global to local space, given LocalOrigin, LocalI, LocalJ, and GloablPoint is (in rough pseudo code)

```
Vec2D PointToLocalSpace(Vec2D GlobalPoint, Vec2D LocalI, Vec2D LocalJ, Vec2D LocalOrigin) {
    offset = GlobalPoint.Subtract(LocalOrigin)
    return new Vector2D(
      offset.Dot(LocalI),
      offset.Dot(LocalJ),
    )
```

(where LocalI and LocalJ are two unit vectors at right angles that specify the x and y axis for local space)

What would be the inverse operation (local to global space)?

Comment: Note that the formula you've listed assumes that LocalI and LocalJ are unit vectors. If they can include local scaling, then you need to divide each dot product by the squared magnitude of that axis vector (which happens to be division by 1 or a no-op for unit vectors).

Answer (score 2):

```cs
WorldPoint = LocalPoint.x * LocalI 
           + LocalPoint.y * LocalJ
           + LocalOrigin;
```

Here the * refers to scalar multiplication (ie. scaling the vector's length up or down by multiplying each component by the scalar value)

Checking if this is right:

- If `LocalPoint = (0, 0)`, then we get `LocalOrigin` exactly.
- If `LocalPoint = (x, 0)`, then we get a point `x` units' distance away from `LocalOrigin` in direction `LocalI`, if that's a unit vector, or `x` times the length of `LocalI` more generally.
- And the same for `y` and `LocalJ`.
- Because this is an affine combination, this holds for any linear combination of `x` and `y`.

Comment: I appreciate that this defines `*`. Sometimes the type of multiplication is obvious, but it's often helpful to just clarify it explicitly as done here. Showing how to double check the math is also nice.